# Tehillim on Shabbos

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, tehilim-psalms

[Seeing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10579/13811) that we 'avoid making requests' on Shabbos, 
may one say Tehillim privately on shabbos for sick, not life-pressing, individuals? Is the halacha different if saying the *mishaberach* after Tehillim or for a zechus like another person's shidduchim?

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65367/why-must-not-we-cry-out-make-petitions-in-shabbat-shabbat-12a/65391#65391

Comment: It's a Machloket Rishonim if you can Daven for life-threateningly sick individuals on Shabbat. Even among those who were lenient, some only permitted it when the sick person is nearby that you know they are still alive. Most are lenient on these two questions and permit praying for a sick person who may die that very day. Otherwise you should delay praying till after Shabbat.

Comment: Are you asking about saying Tehillim and just having this in mind? Or about saying Tehillim followed by a prayer (eg. Mi Sheberach) for X?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the jump from merchandise to davening for the sick. The Gemara says very clearly that public needs are allowed on Shabbos; is your question simply whether davening for the sick is considered a private or public need?

Answer (score 4):

Halichos Shlomo 14:11:19 says that one may say Tehilim on Shabbos for one that is sick if it is done privately (BeYechidus).

Beshivilai Bais Harafua based on Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Aurbach 7:15 says that if the sick person requests that Tehilim should be said for him, it may even be done with a Minyan.

Thanks to [www.shut-halacha.co.il](http://www.shut-halacha.co.il/q/%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA-200?category=) for this answer.